# How to set soapHeader to authenticate in c#?

Tags: c#, web-services

I want to write a c# client to consume a web service ,after i add service reference and get a proxy class , i write code like this:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            servicePortTypeClient sc = new servicePortTypeClient();

            string stID=sc.getTableByTitle("Equipment");
        }
```

but when i run this code, i get a exception of : wrong parameters for authorization

there are some code of how to use this web service,but the code is written by php,below is the sample:

```
  $client = new SoapClient(
    'https://rtu2/mvtspro/extensions/service/?wsdl',
    array(
       'timeout' => 1000
     )
   );
   $headers = array();
   $headers[] = new  SoapHeader('http://merasystems.com/auth','Login','admin');
   $headers[] = new  SoapHeader('http://merasystems.com/auth','Password','admin');
   $client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```

i guess maybe i have some error about how to authenricate with the server,but i don't know how to write code to do it,can anybody figure it out?

below is th wsdl document of the service:

```
        <s:complexType name="rowset">
            <s:complexContent>
                <s:restriction base="ns:Array">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="item" type="ns3:row" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                    <s:attribute ref="ns:arrayType" arrayType="ns3:row[]" />
                </s:restriction>
            </s:complexContent>
        </s:complexType>

        <s:complexType name="row">
            <s:complexContent>
                <s:restriction base="ns:Array">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="item" type="ns3:column" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                    <s:attribute ref="ns:arrayType" arrayType="ns3:column[]" />
                </s:restriction>
            </s:complexContent>
        </s:complexType>

        <s:complexType name="column">
            <s:all>
                <s:element name="name" type="s:string"/>
                <s:element name="value" type="s:string"/>
            </s:all>
        </s:complexType>

        <s:complexType name="sort">
            <s:complexContent>
                <s:restriction base="ns:Array">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="item" type="ns3:sort_item" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                    <s:attribute ref="ns:arrayType" arrayType="ns3:sort_item[]" />
                </s:restriction>
            </s:complexContent>
        </s:complexType>

        <s:complexType name="sort_item">
            <s:all>
                <s:element name="column" type="s:string"/>
                <s:element name="dir" type="ns3:order_type"/>
            </s:all>
        </s:complexType>

        <s:simpleType name="order_type">
            <s:restriction base="s:string">
                <s:enumeration value="asc"/>
                <s:enumeration value="desc"/>
            </s:restriction>
        </s:simpleType>

        <s:complexType name="filter_childs_arr">
            <s:complexContent>
                <s:restriction base="ns:Array">
                    <s:sequence>
                        <s:element name="item" type="ns3:filter" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </s:sequence>
                    <s:attribute ref="ns:arrayType" arrayType="ns3:filter[]" />
                </s:restriction>
            </s:complexContent>
        </s:complexType>

        <s:complexType name="filter">
            <s:all>
                <s:element name="type" type="s:string"/>
                <s:element name="column" type="s:string" nillable="true"/>
                <s:element name="operator" type="s:string" nillable="true"/>
                <s:element name="value" type="s:string" nillable="true"/>
                <s:element name="childs" type="ns3:filter_childs_arr" nillable="true"/>
            </s:all>
        </s:complexType>

    </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<message name="insertRowsetRequest">
    <part name="p_table_hi" type="s:string"/>
    <part name="p_rowset" type="ns3:rowset"/>
</message>
<message name="insertRowsetResponse">
    <part name="result" type="s:integer"/>
</message>
<message name="updateRowsetRequest">
    <part name="p_table_hi" type="s:string"/>
    <part name="p_rowset" type="ns3:rowset"/>
    <part name="p_filter" type="ns3:filter"/>
</message>
<message name="updateRowsetResponse">
    <part name="result" type="s:integer"/>
</message>
<message name="deleteRowsetRequest">
    <part name="p_table_hi" type="s:string"/>
    <part name="p_rowset" type="ns3:rowset"/>
    <part name="p_filter" type="ns3:filter"/>
</message>
<message name="deleteRowsetResponse">
    <part name="result" type="s:integer"/>
</message>
<message name="selectRowsetRequest">
    <part name="p_table_hi" type="s:string"/>
    <part name="p_filter" type="ns3:filter"/>
    <part name="p_sort" type="ns3:sort"/>
    <part name="p_limit" type="s:integer"/>
    <part name="p_offset" type="s:integer"/>
</message>
<message name="selectRowsetResponse">
    <part name="result" type="s:anyType"/>
</message>
<message name="countRowsetRequest">
    <part name="p_table_hi" type="s:string"/>
    <part name="p_filter" type="ns3:filter"/>
</message>
<message name="countRowsetResponse">
    <part name="result" type="s:integer"/>
</message>
<message name="getTableByTitleRequest">
    <part name="p_title" type="s:string"/>
</message>
<message name="getTableByTitleResponse">
    <part name="result" type="s:string"/>
</message>
<message name="describeColumnsRequest">
    <part name="p_table_hi" type="s:string"/>
</message>
<message name="describeColumnsResponse">
    <part name="result" type="s:anyType"/>
</message>
<message name="getColumnLookupRequest">
    <part name="p_table_hi" type="s:string"/>
    <part name="p_column_nm" type="s:string"/>
</message>
<message name="getColumnLookupResponse">
    <part name="result" type="s:anyType"/>
</message>
<portType name="servicePortType">
    <operation name="insertRowset">
        <input message="ns3:insertRowsetRequest"/>
        <output message="ns3:insertRowsetResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateRowset">
        <input message="ns3:updateRowsetRequest"/>
        <output message="ns3:updateRowsetResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="deleteRowset">
        <input message="ns3:deleteRowsetRequest"/>
        <output message="ns3:deleteRowsetResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="selectRowset">
        <input message="ns3:selectRowsetRequest"/>
        <output message="ns3:selectRowsetResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="countRowset">
        <input message="ns3:countRowsetRequest"/>
        <output message="ns3:countRowsetResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getTableByTitle">
        <input message="ns3:getTableByTitleRequest"/>
        <output message="ns3:getTableByTitleResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="describeColumns">
        <input message="ns3:describeColumnsRequest"/>
        <output message="ns3:describeColumnsResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getColumnLookup">
        <input message="ns3:getColumnLookupRequest"/>
        <output message="ns3:getColumnLookupResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="servicePortBinding" type="ns3:servicePortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="insertRowset">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="updateRowset">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="deleteRowset">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="selectRowset">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="countRowset">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getTableByTitle">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="describeColumns">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="getColumnLookup">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://mfisoft.ru/soap"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="Service">
    <port name="ServicePortType" binding="ns3:servicePortBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://111.111.111.20/service/service.php?soap"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send your credentials to the WCF service like this,

```
servicePortTypeClient sc = new servicePortTypeClient();

sc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = yourUserName;
sc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = yourPassword

string stID=sc.getTableByTitle("Equipment");
```

Comment: thank you,i have try this,but still get an exception of "wrong parameters for authorization",is it indicate my username or pwd is not correct?

Comment: this is a third party web service,so i can only get the wsdl document,in the wsdl,i have not find any "soaphead" defination,but the api document of this service do require username and password to authenticate,could anygbody tell me what the reason?